# Identify a POST Request in Fiddler JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fiddler

I'm writing custom rules for Fiddler and am wondering how you identify that a request is a POST (ie. not a GET or other type) request in the JavaScript?  Neither the session nor the request objects seem to have a property that gives this data.

In other words

```
static function IsPostRequest(oSession : Session) {

    if (oSession. <-- WHAT GOES HERE????? ) 
            return true;
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static function IsPostRequest(oSession : Session) {
    return oSession.HTTPMethodIs("POST"); 
}
```